# Splitting a List

Tags: haskell

I wrote the following `split` function. It takes a `list`, an `element` and an `Ordering (LT, GT, EQ)`. For `LT`, the list will filter out all items that are >= the element argument.

```
split' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a -> Ordering -> [a]
split' [] _ _ = []
split' (x:xs) a LT
  | x < a     = x : split' xs a LT
  | otherwise = split' xs a LT 
split' (x:xs) a GT
  | x > a     = x : split' xs a GT
  | otherwise = split' xs a GT
-- non-exhaustive, unacceptable
```

Example:

```
*Main> split' [1,2,3] 2 LT
[1]
```

Note that this function can result in an exception if the `Ordering` argument is `EQ`. Of course this is terrible.

However, please review the above code, offering suggestions on how to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Your `split'` could be simplified using `filter`.

```
split' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a -> Ordering -> [a]
split' list value cmp = filter (\x -> compare x value == cmp) list
```

I think that the order of arguments to `split'` is awkward.  I would suggest that the reverse order is more natural.

```
split :: (Ord a) => Ordering -> a -> [a] -> [a]
split cmp value list = filter (\x -> compare x value == cmp) list

*Main> split LT 2 [1, 2, 3]
[1]
```

Then you could also define `split` in a curried form:

```
split :: (Ord a) => Ordering -> a -> ([a] -> [a])
split cmp value = filter (\x -> compare x value == cmp)
```